# mongodb_store in ROS Indigo require MongoClient package (as specified in the CMakeLists.txt line 9)

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message while trying to make the package:

```
+++ processing catkin package: 'mongodb_store'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(mongodb_store)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at mongodb_store/cmake/FindMongoClient.cmake:72 (message):
  MongoClient not found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mongodb_store/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

The line 9 in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(MongoClient REQUIRED)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217282/mongodb_store-in-ros-indigo-require-mongoclient-package-(as-specified-in-the-cmakelists.txt-line-9),-where-do-i-can-find-this-package,-or-how-can-i-install-it?/) by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [ROS Index](http://rosindex.github.io) page for [mongodb_store](http://rosindex.github.io/p/mongodb_store/#indigo-deps), that package depends (among other things), on [mongodb](http://rosindex.github.io/d/mongodb/) and [mongodb-dev](http://rosindex.github.io/d/mongodb-dev/).

Do you have those packages installed?

---

In general, to make sure you have all dependencies for a ROS pkg you're trying to compile yourself, you should run

```
rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

Provided the package you want to build has declared all its dependencies properly, that should alert you to anything missing.

If you want `rosdep` to also install them for you, replace `check` with `install`.

---

Edit: just to be sure: the `mongodb_store` package has been released in Indigo and Jade, according to its [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_store). If you don't need to work on the package itself, it might be more convenient to just `sudo apt-get install ros-$release-mongodb_store`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on 2015-09-08**:
thanks, great.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-07-26**:
@gvdhoorn, Can you please! update the links. Thanks